# Experiencing different behavior between object initialization in declaration vs. initialization in constructor

Tags: c#, winforms

This is a WinForms C# application.
The following two snippits show two different ways of initializing an object. They are giving different results.

This works as expected:

```
public partial class Form1 : Form
{
  private CameraWrapper cam;
  public Form1()
  {
       cam = new CameraWrapper();
       InitializeComponent();           
  }
```

This does not work (details below):

```
public partial class Form1 : Form
{
  private CameraWrapper cam = new CameraWrapper();
  public Form1()
  {
       InitializeComponent();
  }
```

Inside `CameraWrapper` I am using a third-party SDK to communicate with a camera. I register with an event on the SDK which is called when results are available.

In case 1 (initialization inside constructor), everything works as expected and the event handler inside `CameraWrapper` gets called. In case 2, the event handler never gets called.

I thought that these two styles of object initialization were identical, but it seems not to be the case. Why?

Here is the entire `CameraWrapper` class. The event handler should get called after a call to `Trigger`.

```
class CameraWrapper
{
    private Cognex.DataMan.SDK.DataManSystem ds;
    public CameraWrapper()
    {
        ds = new DataManSystem();
        DataManConnectionParams connectionParams = new DataManConnectionParams("10.10.191.187");
        ds.Connect(connectionParams);

        ds.DmccResponseArrived += new DataManSystem.DmccResponseArrivedEventHandler(ds_DmccResponseArrived);
    }

    public void Trigger()
    {
        SendCommand("TRIGGER ON");
    }

    void ds_DmccResponseArrived(object sender, DmccResponseArrivedEventArgs e)
    {
        System.Console.Write("Num barcodes: ");
        System.Console.WriteLine(e.Data.Length.ToString());
    }

    void SendCommand(string command)
    {
        const string cmdHeader = "||>";
        ds.SendDmcc(cmdHeader + command);
    }
}
```

Comment: It might be helpful to post some of the code from `CameraWrapper` - the above code should function similarly.

Comment: Robert, I tested your hypothesis and the `CameraWrapper` constructor in both cases is being called exactly once.

Comment: So, is your form attaching to the event on the CameraWrapper? Does the event for your camerawrapper fire no matter which constructor version you fire?

Comment: No, the form is not attaching to the event in `CameraWrapper`. The event handler in `CameraWrapper` only fires if I initialize `CameraWrapper` in the main form's constructor.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

> I thought that these two styles of object initialization were identical, but it seems not to be the case.

Not quite.

In the first case, the `CameraWrapper` constructor is called *after* the base class constructor for `Form`. In the second case, the `CameraWrapper` constructor is called, *then* the base class constructor, then the `Form1` constructor body.

It's possible that something within the `Form` constructor affects the execution of the `CameraWrapper` constructor.